# How to fix wrong canvas draw after fixing orientation (orientation 5-8)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

## Issue

Wrong layout of image after fixing orientation (5-8).
I fix exif orientation in images, and its o.k in pictures with orientation 1-4,
but when i try to fix orientation 5-8 the layout is wrong.

## Code

Here is my code:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var orientation = tile.orientation;

if (4 < orientation && orientation < 9) {
   canvas.height = tile.width;
   canvas.width = tile.height;
   } else {
        canvas.width = tile.width;
        canvas.height = tile.height;
   }

switch (orientation) {
   case 2: ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, 1, tile.width, 0); break;
   case 3: ctx.transform(-1, 0, 0, -1, tile.width, tile.height); break;
   case 4: ctx.transform(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, tile.height); break;
   case 5: ctx.transform(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0); break;
   case 6: ctx.transform(0, 1, -1, 0, tile.height, 0); break;
   case 7: ctx.transform(0, -1, -1, 0, tile.height, tile.width); break;
   case 8: ctx.transform(0, -1, 1, 0, 0, tile.width); break;
   default: break;
}
          
ctx.drawImage(tile.imageDataPreview, 0, 0, tile.width, tile.height);
```

## Question

**What should I change to get correct layout?** Thank you.